# How to get background event intersection in fullcalendar V3?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to create background events in full calendar V3 that only show the parts that intersect, in agendaWeek view

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            scrollTime: bStart,
            minTime: '06:00:00',
            maxTime: '18:00:00',
            slotLabelInterval: '01:00',
            defaultDate: moment().format(),
            eventLimit: false,
            navLinks: true,
            dragScroll: false, 

            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'prev,next today',
            },

            views: {
                week: { // name of view
                    titleFormat: 'LL',
                    columnHeaderFormat: 'Do MMM, dddd' 
                    // other view-specific options here
                }
            },

//example with 2 events there can be more
events: [
    {
        start: "2019-04-18 08:00",
        end: "2019-04-18 11:00",
        color: 'red',
        rendering: 'background',

      },
      {
        start: "2019-04-18 09:00",
        end: "2019-04-18 10:00",
        color: 'red',
        rendering: 'background',
      },

    ]
//.......
});
```

What I get is the 9 to 10 slots are a dark red while the 8 to 11 slots are light.
I just want the intersection of the events to be visible on the calendar i.e. 9 to 10

I will be passing a large set of events, we can take an example of e1 - 9 to 10 am on 2019-04-18, e2 - 9:30 to 10:30 am on 2019-04-18 (and so on..), I wanted a way to find the intersection of the events i.e. 9:30 to 10 am, should be displayed on the calendar.

Comment: Not sure I get the point of this...if you only want 9 to 10 to show on the calendar, then don't provide the other event.... or maybe I missed the point. Can you give an example with different data which re-inforces what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I will be passing a large set of events, we can take an example of e1 - 9 to 10 am on 2019-04-18, e2 - 9:30 to 10:30 am on 2019-04-18 (and so on..), I wanted a way to find the intersection of the  events i.e. 9:30 to 10 am, should be displayed on the calendar.

Comment: I suggest you do that server-side and pass only the results of the calculation to fullCalendar. fullCalendar likes to just display whatever you give it. Giving it events that you're then going to remove again when they don't intersect is a bit pointless